# change the objects of just one collectionview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

What I'm trying to do is when I tap the button in a cell, that button in that cell becomes invisible. The problem is when I tap the button, it becomes invisible, but when I scroll the collection view the hidden button goes from one to the other. For example, I tap the second one it hides but when I scroll I see that the 7th becomes hidden. Every time I scroll the hidden button change.

This is the code I wrote:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
   let cell : CollectionViewCellKharid3 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "customcell3", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellKharid3

        cell.lblEsmeMahsul.text = mainCats[indexPath.row]

        cell.imgMahsul.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string : (mainadress + "/Opitures/" + mainPicNumbers[indexPath.row]))!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "loadings" ))


        cell.btnKharid.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnColectionviewCellTapped), for : UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.btnKharid.tag = indexPath.row

         cell.btnMosbat.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnMosbatTapped), for : UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.btnMosbat.tag = indexPath.row


        cell.configureCell()
        return cell
    }

@objc func btnColectionviewCellTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
    // let indexPath : IndexPath = self.collectionview1.ind

    print(sender.tag)

    sender.isHidden = true
}

@objc func btnMosbatTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
    let index = IndexPath(item: sender.tag , section: 0)
    let cell = self.collectionviewForushVije.cellForItem(at: index) as? CollectionViewCellKharid3

    cell?.lblTedad.text = "22"
    print(sender.tag)
}
```

[image]

Comment: override the prepareforreuse func to set all needet stuff. Like visibillity state of the button. The cells are reused and if you dont setup it right, you get problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cells get reused. You need to keep track of which cells have been tapped so you can set the proper button state in your `cellForItemAt` method.

Declare a property in your class:

```
var beenTapped: Set<Int> = []
```

Then in `btnColectionviewCellTapped` add:

```
beenTapped.insert(sender.tag)
```

And in `cellForItemAt` you need:

```
cell.btnKharid.isHidden = beenTapped.contains(indexPath.item)
```

You should also replace the use of `indexPath.row` with `indexPath.item`. `row` is for table views. `item` is for collection views.

Comment: thanks for quick reply. just one more problem. how should I save it permanently? I wrote self.defaults.set(beenTapped, forKey: "beenTapped") but it gives me the error terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException, I printed beenTapped before it and It has value. also when I use another variable insted of beenTapped it works fine!! what should I do?

Comment: You can't store a `Set` in `UserDefaults`. Create an array from the set and store the array.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very common mis-use of UICollectionView(or UITableView). When deal with them, you should alway keep one thing in mind, re-use. The collection/tableview cell will be highly reuse by os when on need. The problem cause in your code is, you assume the one time set of one property in a cell will be persistence, which is wrong. The cell come from dequeue method, can always be a new cell or an existing cell, therefore, any configuration should be apply to a cell should be config again. Think in that way, all view in a cell is "dirty" when it get it from collection view, you should set the property you want before return it back(or have a mechanism to set it later). Therefore, in your case, just set the isHidden property every time you prepare the cell in cellForRow delegate.